# Compile with .NET native tool chain caused System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to build my UWP application in release mode. Every time I compile, I encountered:

> error : Internal compiler error: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

After exhausting research, I found that the problem is caused by **Compile with .NET native tool chain**. When I un-ticked this option (Project Property | Build), my project can be build.

My project isn't very big, but I have 13 projects on the same solutions. They are all just a common components (which are very very small).

I am using VS2015 Community Edition.

Any idea? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. I had the same issue yesterday. I reached out to the MSDN team in charge of VS and I am waiting for a response from them. For now I think the work around is just disabling the Native Tool Chain option. It only defaults on in release mode.

Comment: Thanks mate, please keep us posted on how do you go with the VS team. Love to know when they put out the patch :)